# How to sum over column in pandas dropping value of a given category if values of another are present?

Tags: python, pandas

I downloaded food production data from [FAOSTAT](https://www.fao.org/home/en).
For a given year, production data for a certain foodstuff may be provided as an official value, an estimate or it may be of another category. However, the production values are all given in one column like this:

```
   Area     Y2017   Y2017flags
0  France   10      official
1  USA      11      estimate
2  Germany  12      official
3  Germany  10      estimate
```

For some areas multiple production values are available, e.g. an estimate, an official value, and an unofficial value.

I'd now like to sum over all values in the column `Y2017` but in a conditional way: If an official figure is available for a country, take that value, if not take the estimate, if not take the unofficial value, etc.

Is there a way to do this without splitting the dataframe?

Comment: What is the expected result? `df.sort_values('Y2017flags', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Area')['Y2017'].sum()` = 33?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the DataFrame by the `Area` column and apply the `first()` method to the `Y2017` column with the parameter key, which allows you to specify a function to order the groups before selecting the first value.

```
df.sort_values("Y2017flags", inplace=True)
df = df.groupby("Area").first()
total_sum = df['Y2017'].sum()
```

This will group the dataframe by `Area` and sort the groups by the `Y2017flags` in ascending order. Then, it selects the first value of each group and returns the result in a new dataframe (in case of both `official` and `estimated`, it will give the offical.